# How Can I Convert Request.Form.AllKeys to MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have this code on a sample written on MVC and I want to change it to MVC Core.

```
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            String value = Request.Form[key];
            requestForm.Add(key, value);
        }
```

Actually I changed it to

```
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            String value = Request.Form[key];
            requestForm.Add(key, value);
        }
```

but I'm not sure it works correctly. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this :

```
var dict = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());
foreach (string key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
{
     var a = dict[key];
}
```

In that case, you can iterate over your dictionary or you can access values directly:

```
dict["Hello"] = "World"
```